# How to add uuid in every winston log node js per request?

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I am using winston logger. I want to add **uuid** in every logs having same uuid per request.

> In app.js

```
var distributorapp = require('./routes/distributorapp');
app.use('/dstapp',distributorapp);
```

> In routes/distributorapp.js(Middleware)

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var logger = require('../locallibs/logger');
var uuid = require('uuid/v1');
module.exports = {
    mddlw: function (req, res, next) {
        req.bodyData = qs.parse(req.body); // parsing body and added to request object
        req.uuid = uuid(); // Adding uuid to request to available every where throught request
        callHsmRest(req, res); // function to do some logic and handle middleware functionality
    }
};
```

> In logger.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

if (!fs.existsSync(today)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(today);
}


function customFileFormatter(options) {
    console.log(options);
    return options.timestamp() + ' [' + options.level.toUpperCase() + '] ' + (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') +
            (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '');
}

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            timestamp: function () {
                return moment().format();
            },
            json: false,
            filename: today + '/test.log',
            formatter: customFileFormatter
        })
    ]
});
```

Now in every request I want to generate uuid and add it to request body.So I have added in Middleware.But how it will be available to logger.js in customFileFormatter formatter function?

When some one uses this logger to log any data i want that uuid to be prepended in logger formatter in every logs through request.

If some one require `logger.js` and do

```
logger.info("Hello");
logger.info("Hi");
```

Currently following I have following logs

> 2017-02-24T12:36:23+05:30 [INFO] "Hello"
>     2017-02-24T12:36:23+05:30 [INFO] "Hi"

But I want

> 2017-02-24T12:36:23+05:30 [INFO] c00d6800-fa5f-11e6-83c2-f531bfc95472 "Hello"
>   2017-02-24T12:36:23+05:30 [INFO] c00d6800-fa5f-11e6-83c2-f531bfc95472 "Hi"

---

Also I want to change logger file path according to route middleware.

Currently when request came from `/dstapp` it uses `distributorapp` Middleware and every subsequent logs from this request goes to path `dstapp/2017-02-24/test.log`
But when request came from lets say `/anotherapp` it uses `anotherapp` Middleware and subsequent logs from this request goes to path `anotherapp/2017-02-24/test.log`

I have searched through every where but can't find any solution
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's in the docs https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/blob/master/Readme.md#request-logging instead of formatter you can add a template string -> `transport: {...}, msg: '{{ req.uuid }} '`

Comment: @Molda I'm not using express-winston package. I'm using only winston. can i add `{{req.uuid}}` in winston also as I using callback function for formatter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had to face this same problem. 
I found out a solution using node-uuid library to generate a unique uuid for each request, and continuation-local-storage library to share information among modules.

1º. I added a middleware functionality to create the uuid for each request and add it to the namespace I had created:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var createNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace;
var myRequest = createNamespace('my request');

// Run the context for each request. Assign a unique identifier to each request
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    myRequest.run(function() {
        myRequest.set('reqId', uuid.v1());
        next();
    });
});
```

2º. I wrapped winston library to print get the id of the request and add it to every log, something like this:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace;

// Wrap Winston logger to print reqId in each log
var formatMessage = function(message) {
    var myRequest = getNamespace('my request');
    message = myRequest && myRequest.get('reqId') ? message + " reqId: " + myRequest.get('reqId') : message;
    return message;
};

var logger = {
    log: function(level, message) {
        winstonLogger.log(level, formatMessage(message));
    },
    error: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.error(formatMessage(message));
    },
    warn: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.warn(formatMessage(message));
    },
    verbose: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.verbose(formatMessage(message));
    },
    info: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.info(formatMessage(message));
    },
    debug: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.debug(formatMessage(message));
    },
    silly: function(message) {
        winstonLogger.silly(formatMessage(message));
    }
};
module.exports = logger;
```

With this 2 pieces of code you get it.

To make it easier, I created a library that implements all this, and you can use it as winston, without being worried about all this stuff:
https://github.com/davicente/express-logger-unique-req-id

If you want to get into it a little bit more, you can take a look to this article: https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs

Comment: To make it easier, I created a library that implements all this, and you can use it as winston, without being worried about all this stuff:
https://github.com/davicente/express-logger-unique-req-id

Comment: Originally this looked like a promising solution, but the last commit on `continuation-local-storage` package was Nov. 2017, so I decided not to use it.

Comment: @hmak:  Did you find a good alternative to `continuation-local-storage`?

Comment: @DavidVicente I tried to use your library but it does not log the objects nicely. It works with the simple text logging but not for the rich logging with optional parameters.

Comment: Probably you are right. I made this library as a first approach. If you want to print Objects or arrays, you can use JSON.stringify(my_object)  to pass the objects as string, and print them. If you need something more complex, feel free to clone it or send some PR.

Comment: Is there a way without express .. 
I have a very simple http client

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I made a free adaptation of it to successfully provide a better log tracing. One update: the module 'node-uuid' is deprecated, and has been replaced by 'uuid': https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without use express, maybe do you know some alternative? thanks

Comment: Actually some of the libraries I used for solving this problem are deprecated, so right now I don't know how it could be done, sorry :(

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at AsyncLocalStorage (https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_class_asynclocalstorage), it requires Node.js 12.17.0+, 13.14.0+, or 14.0.0+.

A package which uses this under the hood is: CLS-RTRACER (https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/cls-rtracer)

It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar with [ES6 Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). In middleware I generate unique `requestId` and add it to `app.locals`. Then in `logger.js` I added proxy handler for log functions:

```
let logProxyHandler = {
    apply (target, thisArg, args) {
        var app = getApp(),
            id = '';
        // Some requests do not have unique ID  
        if (app && app.locals && app.locals.requestId) {
            id = `[${app.locals.requestId}]`;
        }
        args[0] = `${id} ${args[0]}`;
        return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args);
    }
}
```

And then add this:

```
logger.info = new Proxy(logger.info, logProxyHandler)
```

Comment: But app.locals is shared by all application, so if 2 requests arrive together, only the last requestId is going to stay, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found way around for this.

> In app.js

```
var logger = require('./locallibs/logger');
app.use(logger)
app.use('/dstapp',distributorapp);
```

> My logger.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var uuid = require('uuid/v1');
if (!fs.existsSync(today)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(today);
}


function customFileFormatter(options) {
    return options.timestamp() + ' [' + options.level.toUpperCase() + '] ' + uuid() + ' ' + (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') +
            (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '');
}

winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(winston.transports.File,
        {
            timestamp: function () {
                return moment().format();
            },
            json: false,
            filename: today + '/test.log',
            formatter: customFileFormatter
        }
);

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    next()
};
```

> In any file

```
var logger = require('winston');
logger.info("First Log");
logger.info("Second Log");
```

> Output is

```
2017-02-24T18:51:39+05:30 [INFO] 2cf92c90-fa94-11e6-83ba-ebaf5a4e7acd First Log
2017-02-24T18:51:39+05:30 [INFO] 2cf9c8d0-fa94-11e6-83ba-ebaf5a4e7acd Second Log
```

Comment: But this writes differents ids for the same request, right?

Comment: with this approach, isn't that you will only see an uuid appear once in your whole log file ?

Comment: @MartinGian No. Uuid will only change of different request.

Comment: @ThắngPQ Yes, On every request new uuid is generated and attached to a logger. So if we log anything in the same request, the same uuid is shared.

Comment: I don't think so. Suppose I invoke async funcA() which invokes async funcB(). Both functions have logger.info. In this case 2 logging will have 2 different uuid because customFileFormatter would be invoked separately for each logger.info(). Later when look at log, we cannot find relation between 2 function calls

Comment: @ThắngPQ May be. I haven't tested this scenario. Also, I stopped using node js. So do you have any perfect answer to this question? I already marked this answer as accepted. If you or others have any perfect answer then will mark this as accepted.

what about the answer from David Vicente?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65522626/1190388 is the best solution, nest-pino implements this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use logFormatter from winston to add more fields to each logs:-

One example below for adding reqId to each logger:

```
const { format} = require("winston");
var reqId = '123123' //use your uuid generator function here
const addRequestId = format((info, opts) => {
    if(reqId)
        info.reqId= reqId;
    return info;
});
```

Then add below config while creating log

```
var config = {
format: format.combine(
  addRequestId(),
  format.timestamp(new Date().toISOString()),
  format.json(),
),
transports: [new transports.Console()],
level: 'debug'
 }
const logger = createLogger(config);
```

Be aware that, when multiple requests occur simultaneously, reqId may be overwritten. This is only suitable for low volume applications. To prevent this problem, you need to use classes to create a separate container for each request flow. Use the parent class as a space to store the reqId that can be accessed by the logger. Not advisable for existing applications.